# can anyone tell me where is the mistakes?

Tags: c, txt

While the program is running , in the middle of it (after typing the    Vaccine name ) it stops and gives me {Exception Thrown} can anyone    help me fix this issue? I have also included a photo of the error it    gives me

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        int choose, dosage, quantity;
        char code[10];
        char name[32];
        char produce[64];
        float population;
        {
            printf("COVID-19 Vaccination System \n");
            printf("1:- Inventory Creation \n");
            printf("2:- Update Vaccine Quantities \n");
            printf("3:- Search Vaccine \n");
            printf("4:- Produce a list of all Vaccines and their distributed Quantities \n");
            printf("5:- EXIT \n\n");
            printf("==>");
            scanf_s("\n%d", &choose);
            if (choose == 1)
            {
                char ch;
                FILE* cv;
                errno_t err;
                err = fopen_s(&cv, "vaccine.txt", "w");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Full information %d \n", i + 1);
                    printf(" Name of Vaccine : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%s", &name);
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Code %c \n", i + 1);
                    printf(" Vaccine Code : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%s", &code);
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Producing Country %c \n", i + 1);
                    printf("Producing Country : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%s", &produce);
                    printf("Please Enter Dosage Required %d \n", i + 1);
                    printf("Dosage Required (MAX=2 - MIN=1) : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%d", &dosage);
                    printf("Please Enter Population Covered %d \n", i + 1);
                    printf("Population Covered (%) : ");
                    scanf_s("\n%f", &population);
                    printf("Please Enter Vaccine Quantity %d \n", i + 1);
                    scanf_s("\n%d", &quantity);
    
                    fprintf("%s %s %s %d %f %d", name, code, produce, dosage, population, quantity);
                }
            }
            
        }
        return 0;

}
```

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-160 [... *Specify the sizes for all c, C, s, S, or string control set [] parameters.* ...]

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), `scanf_s` should take two arguments whenever you use `%s` - One arg for the pointer to the buffer, and a second arg for the size of the buffer.

Comment: Is there a scanf_s() overload that does not require the size argument?   If not, how does it build?

Comment: Why are you using `scanf_s` instead of `scanf`? It is because Microsoft Visual Studio told you to do so? If that is the case, then I recommend that you disable this error message, by adding `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the start of your code (before any `#include` directives).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That is bad advice.  `scanf` can overflow the input buffer.  `scanf_s` exists for a reason (and it's a shame that it has not been adopted by other vendors).

Comment: @PaulSanders: The problem is that Microsoft, in the default settings, requires you to sometimes use non-portable functions. This coincides with Microsoft's [embrace, extent and exterminate policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace%2C_extend%2C_and_extinguish). That is why, in my opinion, this "error" message provided by Microsoft should be disabled by default.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have no problem with `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` - I use it myself - but I do have a problem with `scanf`, when a better / safer alternative exists.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
fprintf("%s %s %s %d %f %d", name, code, produce, dosage, population, quantity);
```

is wrong. You have to pass a file pointer as the first argument of `fprintf()`. It should be:

```
fprintf(cv, "%s %s %s %d %f %d", name, code, produce, dosage, population, quantity);
```

Also

- You should check if `fopen_s` succeeded before proceeding to next operation and stop operation if it failed.
- You should remove `&` before the array names (`code`, `name`, `produce`) used in `scanf_s`. Array in expressions (excluding some exceptions) are automatically converted to pointers to the first element, so no explicit `&` is not needed here. Also it will make the type wrong `scanf()` expects `char*` for `%s`, but things like `&code` are an pointers to arrays (like `char(*)[10]`).

Comment: I believe that what is causing the undefined behavior is not what you describe in the question, but rather the wrong number of parameters for the `%s` format specifier in the variadic `scanf_s` function call (see comments for further information).